# Exceção ao tentar abrir modal

Tags: angular

**Erro**

> ERROR Error:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MeuComponent -> Renderer]: StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MeuComponent -> Renderer]:
>
> NullInjectorError: No provider for Renderer!
>
> at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
>
> at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
>
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
>
> at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
>
> at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
>
> at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
>
> at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
>
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
>
> at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
>
> at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChildren, ElementRef, Renderer, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private renderer: Renderer,private renderer2: Renderer2) 

public showModal(modal: string): void {
  if (modal == 'modalEditar') {
    this.modalEditVisible = true;
    this.modalAddVisible = false;
  }
  else if (modal == 'modalAdicionar') {
    this.modalEditVisible = false;
    this.modalAddVisible = true;
  }
}
editar(obj) {
  this.Component.Objeto= obj;
  this.showModal('modalEditar');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <label (click)="editar(obj)" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-obj-edit">
   <i class="fa fa-pencil text-info"></i>
  </label>
</td>

// Chamada do modal
<app-editar *ngIf="modalEditVisible != false" [(visible)]="modalEditVisible"></app-editar>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">TITULO</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" *ngIf="visible" (click)="close()">×</button>
    </div>
```

**Procedimento**

Ao clicar no icone de editar na minha lista, nada acontece e ao abrir o console do navegador vejo o erro acima. No meu `module`, em `providers` eu tentei colocar o `Renderer`, aparece essa mensagem:

```
O tipo 'typeof Renderer' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'Provider'.
O tipo 'typeof Renderer' não pode ser atribuído ao tipo 'TypeProvider'.
Não é possível atribuir um tipo de construtor abstrato a um tipo de 
construtor não abstrato
```

Comment: Qual o framework do modal que você está tentando abrir? Bootstrap? Coloque o trecho html ou ts referente ao modal

Comment: Usa o renderer2 o renderer ja foi deprecado

Comment: entao, mas o erro esta justamente no renderer. E eu tentei fazer com o renderer2 tambem, da a mesma mensagem

Comment: ve se o modulo que vc declarou seu componente importa o commonsmodule

Comment: Este? import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

Comment: eu tenho outro component/view que tem faz o q eu quero, desde ontem estou comparando todos os arquivos entre eles e nao consigo achar o que tem de diferente... Inclusive usa o mesmo module, este que postei é o editar, o modal que eu quero eu tenho no adicionar

Comment: Abri o component do modal e coloquei o EditarComponent nos imports, criei uma propriedade e chamei ela e funcionou....

Comment: Ola @LeoHenrique, Não altere o titulo da pergunta para indicar que seu problema foi resolvido. Você pode responder sua pergunta e mais tarde aceitar a resposta, isso vai ajudar a pessoas com o mesmo problema =D -- [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @IcaroMartins Perdão... Ok, vou dar uma olhada

Comment: @LeoHenrique, não há necessidade de pedido de desculpa. =D  -  Só comentei para você saber/entender o porquê da reversão. E o `você pode responder sua pergunta` é uma informação para caso você queria deixar sua pergunta como respondida e ajudar a comunidade, você também pode excluir ela se desejar.  =D

Comment: Duvida @IcaroMartins é comum as pessoas excluirem ou auto responder quando elas mesmas conseguem resolver?

Comment: @LeoHenrique,  Eu diria que os dois são comuns e ainda existe uma 3 opção que é a pergunta ficar sem resposta. O modelo do SOpt incentiva o auto responder.

Comment: Eu diria que, se vc achou a solução, o melhor é vc mesmo responder, pois assim o conteúdo será útil para outras pessoas que visitarem o site futuramente (e que estejam com o mesmo problema). É bem frustrante quando a gente acha um link com o exato problema que estamos tendo, e que diz que o problema foi resolvido, mas não diz como: https://xkcd.com/979/ :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo puts, real.. Ja fiquei bem p da vida por achar a possivel solução do meu erro, entrar no site e ver que não tava solucionada haha... Tudo bem então, irei postar, agradeço o feedback de todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer da seguinte forma, dentro do component do meu modal, eu vi que so tava com o import do component de adicionar conforme dito neste comentario:

`eu tenho outro component/view que tem faz o q eu quero, desde ontem estou comparando todos os arquivos entre eles e nao consigo achar o que tem de diferente... Inclusive usa o mesmo module, este que postei é o editar, o modal que eu quero eu tenho no adicionar`

Simplesmente sim, só fiz isso, importei o EditarComponent e coloquei como paramentro do construtor, este component...